# How can I pass a custom argument to an event listener in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

How can I add an event listener (addEventListener(),attachEvent()) that also accepts a parameter?

The parameter is passed as the element's custom attribute like:

```
<img src="icon.gif" alt="Test button" command="test" />
<img src="icon2.gif" alt="Test button2" command="write" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
element.addEventListener ( 'click', (function ( myParam ) {
    return function () {
        // user myParam here
    };
} ) ( yourParam ), false );
```

whatever you pass in as "yourParam" will be accessible to the event handler via the "myParam" parameter ...

Comment: this worked for me:
attachEvent('onclick', function() {
                    linkClicked(link.getAttribute("command"));
                }, false);

Answer (score 3):

You can use getAttribute in your handler, something like

`var param = this.getAttribute('command');`